# Create an GET in jQuery

Tags: jquery, get

In PHP it's `file.php?id=1` and then `$_GET['id']` but how is it in jQuery? I have tried following but that didn't work.

```
// jQuery
$('id-' + $1).click(function() {
    // more code
}

// HTML
<div id="id-1">text</div>
```

I'm new to `GET` in jQuery so please be nice :P

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should parse location.search:

```
var GET = {};
var params = location.search.substr(1).split("&");
for (var i=0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var par = params[i].split('=');
    GET[par[0]] = par[1];
}

$('#id-' + GET["id"]).click(function() {
    // more code
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id-' + GET["id"]).click(function() {
        $('#forecast').show().load('jquery-fetch/fetch-forecast.php?coor=' + GET["coor"] + '&d=' + $(this).attr('id'));
        $('#current').hide();
    });
});​

// HTML
<div id="id-1">text</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer but it didn't work for me :( I copy-pasted your code to my source code and tested it - nothing happened when I clicked on the link and everything looks like yours.

Comment: The console in Chrome (CTRL + SHIFT + J) does not shows any error upon click on the link.

Comment: what does $_GET["coor"] do in your js? Do you include it in the javascript, like: <script src="x.js?coor=1"></script>? What's your js look like when you view it in the browser (with the php part evaluated)?

Comment: `$_GET["coor"]` contains this: `59378217,13504219`. I have my JavaScript code within SCRIPT tags (of course outside the PHP tags) in `fetch-weatherdata.php` which contains all the information about the weather from the visitors coordinates. I can share my ScreenLeap link if you want to see how everything is made.

Comment: http://www.screenleap.com/566456087. We can go in to chat but I don't know how to do it without the direct link to the chat room

Comment: i don't seem to be able to see anything. Can you edit your original question and put there all your files? html, php, js, ...

Comment: I'm sorry. I hope you can see now :) I forgot to resume the sharing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9980/discussion-between-erik-edgren-and-flocsy)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean GUP (get url parameters)?

In javascript, this has nothing to do with GET, GET is a method the browser uses to formulate the request to the server. To fetch the URL parameter from JS do this:

```
var gup = function( name ) {
    var results = (new RegExp("[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)")).exec(window.location.href);
    if ( results == null ) {return ""}
    else {return results[1]}
};
```

Where name is the string you want to retrieve.

```
$('id-' + $1).click(function() {
    var myId = gup("id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for, though it's just pure JS, not sure if there's an easier way with jQuery:

```
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

Then use it like:

```
var id_param = gup( 'id' );
```

From http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html

Comment: Thanks but how do I fetch the id from my DIV tag (`<div id="id-1">text</div>`) with this GUP?

Comment: Disregard my answer, because you mentioned file.php?id=1 and $_GET I thought you were trying to get the value of id from the query string, not from an html element.